# Magento 1.9.1.1 - Duplicate results displayed

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a Magento issue.  I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.1.1.

The issue is that I am seeing duplicate results for a page which contains a list of jobs (its a recruitment page).  The problem is each of the results is duplicated.  I've never done any real Magento development before and it seems like a steep learning curve.

I've checked the content and that has only been entered once.

This is the offending code:

```
//I tried this line with no effect
//$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->distinct(true);

// $collection contains the duplicate results
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
```

Can anyone give me any ideas on how I can solve this?  Even an idea of where to look in the code would be good.

I've found two data structures when iterating through the collection.  These are `_origData` and `_Data`.  Don't know why its using both of these but I managed to fix/hack it by doing:

```
if($key == "_origData"){
   continue;
}
```

Surely there's a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying filters to your collection?

See below:

```
$getStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
              ->addStoreFilter($getStoreId)
              ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
```

**Resources:**

- [Class Mage_Cms_Model_Mysql4_Page_Collection](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Cms/Mage_Cms_Model_Mysql4_Page_Collection.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the code details on above mentioned Model class.But if you want custom code you can try like this  :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(
        array('s' => $collection->getTable('cms/page_store')),
        's.page_id = main_table.page_id AND s.store_id != 0',
        array('store_id')
    )
    ->columns(array('stores_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(s.store_id)')))
    ->group('main_table.page_id')
    ->having('stores_count = ?', 1)
    ->having('s.store_id = ?', $storeId)
;
```